# Simple javascript validation form, but I'm completely new to JS

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a blog where Id like to use a small JS textarea validation.

Basically what I want it to do is that it checks for a certain string

*'the string I want to check'.*

I want it to validate these exact words, and if it's incorrect I want it to say

*incorrect! do you need more help?*

But when it's correct, I want it to say

*Correct! Go to the next question.*

my problem is I don't have any JS experience, but searching through stackoverflow and google got my quite far I think. I'm not getting the output I want though.. 
Could someone take a quick look and adjust it a little?

```js
function validateForm() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');

  var word = ('the string I want to check');

  var textValue = textarea.value;

  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    alert('Correct! Go to the next question!)
  } else {
    return false
    alert('Incorrect! Do you need more help? Try the hint button.')
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareabox" name="powershellarea"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: [Open the browser's console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), the error message tells where the problem is. Also, `return` returns from the function immediately so the alert after it can never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `return false;` from the else block.

With that return, the code exits the function before the alert executes and is then never shown.

You're also missing a closing quote `'` from a string.

```
function validateForm() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');

  var word = 'the string I want to check';

  var textValue = textarea.value;

  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    alert('Correct! Go to the next question!')
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect! Do you need more help? Try the hint button.')
  }
}
```

If you want the function to return `true` or `false` after displaying the alert, you can do so as follows:

```
function validateForm() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');

  var word = 'the string I want to check';

  var textValue = textarea.value;

  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    alert('Correct! Go to the next question!');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect! Do you need more help? Try the hint button.');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wauw thank you very much for helping me! It seems like I was close to a solution :-). thank you very much.